# Using the iterative method find terms in the asymptotic expansion of the roots of this polynomial

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I have been given the question: "Find the first three terms in the asymptotic expansions as $x^3 + x - \epsilon = 0$ of the roots of $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$
using the iterative method."

The method of iteration is stated as follows:

- You find the first term of the asymptotic expansion by finding the roots when $\epsilon = 0$.

For this example: You find $x^3 + x= 0$ which has roots $x = 0$ and $x = \pm i$

- Rearrange the original equation to find an iterative process:

For this equation I have rearranged the equation into: $x_n = \epsilon -x_{n-1}^3$.

Using this equation and the starting point x = 0, we get $x = \epsilon + - \epsilon^3 + 3\epsilon^5 + ...$  This seems to work for x = 0.

However when I put in $x = \pm i$, the iterative method doesn't come out with constant coefficients.

Does anybody know if this method works for complex numbers or if my method is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the expansion
to be for small values of the parameter.

For the root, say,
$x=i$,
you want to consider
$i+c$ for small $c$.

So,
if $x_n = i+c_n$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
i+c_{n+1}
&=\epsilon-(i+c_n)^3\\
&=\epsilon-(i^3+3i^2c_n+3ic_n^2+c_n^3)\\
&=\epsilon-(-i-3c_n+3ic_n^2+c_n^3)\\
&=\epsilon+i+3c_n-3ic_n^2-c_n^3\\
\text{so}\\
c_{n+1}
&=\epsilon+3c_n-3ic_n^2-c_n^3\\
\end{array}
$

Starting with
$c_0 = 0$,
$c_1 = \epsilon$,
$c_2
=\epsilon+3\epsilon-3i\epsilon^2-\epsilon^3
=4\epsilon-3i\epsilon^2-\epsilon^3
$,
and so on.

---

(added later)

Looking at this,
I am perturbed by the fact that
the coefficient of
$\epsilon$ changes from
$c_1$ to $c_2$.
I don't see anything wrong,
so I'll leave it at this.
If I made a mistake,
maybe someone
will find something.

Comment: This answer has clicked something in my mind. I didn't of the actual processes behind the method, i.e. perturbing around the root. Thank you :)